# Discord bot connection is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a discord music bot with a queue feature and I keep getting the following error.
How do I define the connection?

I have tried adding the line

```
const connection = await message.member.voice.channel.join();
```

to define connection but when i add that i get a different error saying that connection is already declared.

```
(node:14724) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: connection is not defined
    at Client.<anonymous> (E:\Crashbot\index.js:493:14)
    at Client.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (E:\Crashbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (E:\Crashbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (E:\Crashbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (E:\Crashbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (E:\Crashbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (E:\Crashbot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:125:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (E:\Crashbot\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:797:20)
(node:14724) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:14724) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

```
var servers = {};

function play(connection, message) {
    var server = servers[message.guild.id];

    //const connection = await message.member.voice.channel.join();

    const dispatcher = connection.play(ytdl(server.queue[0], { filter: 
        "audioonly" }));

    server.dispatcher = connection.play(ytdl(server.queue[0], { filter: 
    "audioonly" })).then(()=> {
        playing = true;
    });


    dispatcher.on('error', console.error);

    server.dispatcher.setVolume(0.2);

    server.dispatcher.on("end", function () {

        server.queue.shift();

    if (server.queue[0]) play(connection, message);
    else connection.disconnect().then(()=> {
        playing = false;
    });

});
}



Crashbot.on('message', async message =>{

    //let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");
    let args = message.content.toString().substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

switch (args[0]) {
 case "play":
        if (!args[1]) {
            message.reply(`You need to put a link after ${PREFIX}play to add a song to the queue`)
            return;
        }
        if (!message.member.voice.channel) {
            message.channel.send("You must be in a voice channel to use this command")
            return;
        }
        if (!servers[message.guild.id]) servers[message.guild.id] = {
            queue: []
        }
        var server = servers[message.guild.id];

        server.queue.push(args[1]);
        play(connection, message);


        if (!message.guild.voiceConnection) message.member.voice.channel.join().then(function (connection) {
                play(connection, message);
        });
        break;

 case "skip":
        var server = servers[message.guild.id];

        if (server.dispatcher) server.dispatcher.end();
        break;
 case "queue":
        message.channel.send(queue);
        break;

 case "stop":
        var server = servers[message.guild.id];

        if (message.guild.voiceConnection) message.guild.voiceConnection.disconnect().then(()=> {
            playing = false;
        });
        break;
}
})
```

Comment: Try to define the connection inside the case "play", above where you call the function.

Comment: `connection` is the first parameter name.

Comment: alright I gave that a try but it gave me the same error.

Comment: I tried adding a line I used earlier in my code that I think defines it 
```
const connection = await message.member.voice.channel.join();
```
but when I try running the bot with this it spits back a very very long error and then crashes (Im new to coding this is probably a simple fix I just dont understand what im doing wrong)